# jpegoptim doesnt compress file

Tags: image, pagespeed, jpegoptim

I have jpegoptim version 1.2.3, and PageSpeed Insights says that I can reduce my image [image] by 36,6 KB (95 %). But using `jpegoptim image.jpg --strip-all
image.jpg 147x196 24bit JFIF  [OK] 39227 --> 39227 bytes (0.00%), skipped.` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

jpegoptim could not compress lossless your image, you could add `--max=60` to force lossy compression.

A lot of online JPEG optimizers (compressjpeg.com, tinyjpg.com) use lossy compressions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the image through [Compress JPG](http://compressjpeg.com/) and reduced it to 12K.

[image: Compressed Image]